# JNLP get a permission

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, jnlp, java-web-start

I recently stumbled across a problem when starting my application via JNLP. I now narrowed it down to a `java.security.AccessControlException`, which denies me to shut down my `ExecuterService`.

So, I did some reading and found out that I'll need the permission (`modifyThread`) to successfully shut down the service. I also found out that I should use the `<security>`-tag (in the JNLP-file) to request it, but I'm a little confused about how.

The [documentation of the tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#security) says:

> [...] If the **`all-permissions` element is specified, the application
>   will have full access to the client machine and local network**. If an
>   application requests full access, then all **JAR files must be
>   signed**. The **user will be prompted** [...]

From reading this it seems to me, that I can choose to either get *all* or *no* permissions... which seems like a confusing Implementation. Because I only need the one to shutdown my service.

I also read [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html), telling me that I should not request all permissions, because I would then open up the users computer for malicious code.

So, is there a way to specify that I only need the specific permission (`modifyThread`) and I therefor don't need to sign my jar? Or will I have to go with the "sign my jar and request everything"-approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ..will I have to go with the "sign my jar and request everything"-approach?

Yes.  JWS permissions come in 3 levels<sup>1</sup>, the only one where modifying threads is permitted, is `all-permissions`.

### 1) JWS security levels

- Sand-boxed.  Provides a very limited environment.  Access to things like printers and the local file-system is only permitted using the JNLP API services, which provide more limited forms of `File` after prompting the user.  Come with window banners.  Can only communicate with own server.
- `j2ee-application-client-permissions` - provide those JNLP API services unprompted (after the user accepts the digitally signed code) removes the window banners.
- **`all-permissions`** - pretty much anything, including replacing the existing security manager (yes, even 'all permissions' code gets a security manager in JWS - it is just very lenient).

Also chase the links from the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) & [JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) pages.  I can personally recommend those summaries & links.

Comment: Thanks thought. Any documentation on those "three levels"?

Comment: Nice, thanks. By the way, do I really need to purchase a 500$ certificate or is there any drawback when using a self-signed certificate (the application will only be used by people I personally know, not everyone)?

Comment: *"is there any drawback when using a self-signed certificate"*  The problem with a self-signed cert. is that just as you can make one claiming you are who you are, so can I make one that claims ***I*** am who you are.  They are 'not worth the bits they are written on'.  OTOH *"only be used by people I personally know"*  So long as you can get them to trust it and click 'OK' when prompted, it will work.